# How to visualize a range on the X axis (MsCharts)

Tags: c#, winforms, data-visualization, mschart

I am trying to create a range of #'s for each point on my X axis.

For Example

I have my Minimum value at 50 and my Maximum value at 2000

My Delta would be 2000-50  = 1950

I will have random values so... 50,100,200,150,350,56,43,21,700,43,854,1795,1994, you get the point, Id like define my X axis to show ranges such as 50-300 and 300-500 and 500 - 800 etc and have my values fall into those ranges, How would I achieve this on MsCharts? Any tips would be appreciated , thanks.

Comment: anyone know an optimal way to do this?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any of your code.  You can always set the x-axis maximum and minimum. `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 50;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1950;`

Comment: well I'd need to be able to make it dynamic, any values that get accepted i find the max and min and then i distribute a range lets say divided 10

Comment: Once you know the values, you can set the axis minimums and maximums and the chart will update.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about a `RangeBar` chart, possibly in connection with a custom legend showing your ranges.